# Development Platform for Small application

Tags: programming-languages

I will soon be developing an application to log and priorities worker shifts. It only needs to be small, and simple, but I am wondering what framework to use. All that needs to happen is boxes with names are in 3 lists, and the user can switch these around at will. It must log the times, which I will need access to in real time.

Im new to application development of this sort, and would like any suggestions. I have time to learn new technologies / languages.

Portability / device independence would also be useful. Should I consider a Web Application in Javascript? or something more like Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your application is going to be simple that does not mean that whole system will be simple too. I can imagine that your app will serve only as a front end to something much bigger. If that is a case and you really have freedom to choose what language you will develop your app with consider choosing something that you will feel comfortable to work with. But before you will make your decision I would go to whoever gave you that task and try to get as much information about it as you can because expected features can help in choosing technology.

First of all, it seems that it is up to you to decide if it should be web or desktop app. In my opinion it is completely wrong situation. You should get clear requirements on what kind of application customer expects and in what environment it should work. And I would not move a finger towards a code before somebody gave me that information. You write that portability and device independence would be useful but is it actual requirement or you just think it would be nice feature to deliver?

**EDITED** (to answer a question in comment)

Probably there is as much possible solutions as people that would answer you so in the end you will have to make your own choices.

One way of doing it (considering that you want to learn something new and have a challenge :) would be implement WCF service that would act as a data provider from your database (so every GetUsers(), GetVacationDays() methods would be in it) and it would take care of some business logic (for example CalculateMaxValidWorkingTime() or whatever). That service would be a real power horse of your system. Since you don't have clear requirement whether it should be desktop or web app you could satisfy both possibilities by creating thin clients that would communicate with your service and they would be just a pretty front ends. And if you keep in mind that you can consume webservices practically with everything from C++ to .NET (C#/VB) to Javascript to Python to PHP after you done with service you would not be constrained with one particular technology/language.

Regarding databases I won't advice because personally I hate dealing with them and it always was somebody else's task to provide me with pretty API :)

Comment: Thanks, this is more a less a side project, and its less of what they want, more of what I can design and give them. Your right, this will be bigger than what I am currently describing, and need to think forward.  There will be some sort of underlying database that (in the future) multiple small applications will use. Any suggestions from seasoned coders as to what framework / language / idea's to use?  Ignore my previous skills as this is a chance to not only get it right, get some paid learning for myself.